# About Moderately Decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

A function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is said of moderate decrease if there is a $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|g(x)| \leq \frac{M}{1 + |x|^{\alpha}}$, for some $\alpha > 1$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Supose $f$ is continuous and such that $f(x) = O(\frac{1}{x^\alpha})$ when $|x| \to + \infty$. Is $f$ of moderate decrease?

Comment: No, because there is no bound near 0.

Comment: 0 is not included, because it is when $|x| \to + \infty$. So there is a $x_0 > 0 $ such that if $|x| \geq x_0$, $f(x) = O(\frac{1}{x^\alpha})$. So, inside $[-x_0, x_0]$, $f$ is limited, and decreases slower than $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ outside the interval.

Comment: If you assume continuity or bounds on f, sure. But that's not a consequence of the big O estimate you wrote down.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add continuity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1+|x|^{\alpha} )|f(x)| \leq 2|x|^{\alpha} |f(x)|$ so  $|f(x)| \leq  \frac {2|x|^{\alpha} |f(x)|} {(1+|x|^{\alpha} )}$ for $|x| >1$.  I hope this answers your question. (There are several errors in the statement; for example you have written 'for all $x \in \mathbb R$' in the definition which is not what you meant).

Comment: If $f$ is of moderate decrease, doesn't that mean that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|f(x)| \leq \frac{M}{1 + x^\alpha}$? Please, point out the errors for me. Maybe I should not have used $f$ for the definition and for the function of the problem. But I really don't see the errors.

Comment: Is $x^{\alpha}$  defined for $x<0$?. A natural  definition of moderate decrease should say $|f(x)| \leq \frac M {1+|x|^{\alpha}}$ for $|x|$ sufficiently large, for some $M \in (0,\infty)$ and some $\alpha >0$.

Comment: I see your point. The definition in my textbook says for all $x$ and and $\alpha = 2$. Also, we should have $\alpha > 1$ so you can integrate over $\mathbb{R}$. I edited the question according to your corrections. Thank you.

Comment: $\alpha >0$ was  a typo in  my comment. Including all $x$ means that the author wants some control for bounded $x$ also but it is not concerned with how the function decreases as $|x| \to \infty$.